# Youtube m3u8 url not playing with video js and hls

Tags: youtube, http-live-streaming, video.js, m3u8, hls.js

I have created an API in PHP in which through URL , we can get live streaming urls ([Twitch](https://www.twitch.tv/) and [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/)) having **m3u8** files in response.  My response will have **m3u8** urls.

Sample  live streaming urls -

Twitch - https://www.twitch.tv/esl_csgo

Youtube - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_Ojv8bOa1Gs

And here is how I play my m3u8 link.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset=utf-8 />
    <title>Your title</title>
      
    
      <link href="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/video.js/dist/video.js"></script>
      <script src="https://unpkg.com/videojs-contrib-hls/dist/videojs-contrib-hls.js"></script>
       
    </head>
    <body>
      <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
      data-setup='{}'>
        <source src="https://video-weaver.cdg02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CucDGIOS2yxm4UFRr4FVg1PjxJRaQW0WYXmZwv8WJ_-pEsi133hf3RGjXG7kHFPuRTsOdhGTIsEXdFlgJzl7DqyuLZ8NbWBIIfaScwy13CbM2IngkOc5et87Wmlws22Uf4XtnvIGxrIlhXkjULdc8mOmRNl0DDhE1OG3MQL2D1zNIySPcT0H0GdVGXYuBW-IyHDXkHOzvEqjSjSztCfQWv2thCLHhN99xOT4XcRZrRezbpR-OlpezC8r0svUsbioABdYiS-LY9oBl86ObM48TbvfQOec4ju8SAW603GOI0bU614CZpthHf0lTchWi6DAmyTNgsre8ICarkqJ_UrSRc3V2gExDoj1FkUjoN0qpd7oHYk196J7OwXSrfMYnxmQfqXCCVK139NASKGFTGeMfy8JLUYEvnRH1vnUvLKhBsJ7vbMgLmccLLHl6rq5K2zpXq9DZlOjIe4wJHG5wA33nW36rnv1e6Sr4sjBGJbGZqjVYA_uIz3SPk_nVFwjN3waA0K1Hcv7uNXHJxuDy0A8fqS3zc99SBMYw2dGYeF4boIMXwfekabL9WpgtZ2km72xKItU6LnPeufgNVQxaIK9ObhyM0Amd8zsjWtsaJ3UhVrd4mdv6PEaqkJwVMx3pC7CkgQdZW4msKjF3hIQxpkK3CxmqD9sSB4scgA1zRoMw9RP45NnK_dgYB1x.m3u8" type="application/x-mpegURL">
      </video>
      
    <script>
    var player = videojs('my_video_1');
    player.play();
    </script>
      
    </body>
    </html>
```

As you can see here, I have used **[video.js](https://videojs.com/)** and **hls** to make this demo working.

But the problem is, My Youtube m3u8 files are not working. It keeps telling me...

> The media could not be loaded, either because the server or network failed or because the format is not supported.

I have researched and It saying something like this - https://support.drugtestingcourses.com/article/157-video-playback-error-media-could-not-be-loaded-either-because-the-server-or-network-failed-or-because-the-format-is-not-supported

But I have tested this and it seems everything is fine .. I even try to test this their online testing urls here

https://codepen.io/furkankinyas/pen/PpXKwO
https://hls-js.netlify.app/demo/

But it seems same thing happening ..

Can someone help me how can I make my **m3u8** youtube urls play ? Do I need to use another player or what ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try :

```
 <video id="my_video_1" class="video-js vjs-fluid vjs-default-skin" controls preload="auto"
  data-setup='{}' src="https://video-weaver.cdg02.hls.ttvnw.net/v1/playlist/CucDGIOS2yxm4UFRr4FVg1PjxJRaQW0WYXmZwv8WJ_-pEsi133hf3RGjXG7kHFPuRTsOdhGTIsEXdFlgJzl7DqyuLZ8NbWBIIfaScwy13CbM2IngkOc5et87Wmlws22Uf4XtnvIGxrIlhXkjULdc8mOmRNl0DDhE1OG3MQL2D1zNIySPcT0H0GdVGXYuBW-IyHDXkHOzvEqjSjSztCfQWv2thCLHhN99xOT4XcRZrRezbpR-OlpezC8r0svUsbioABdYiS-LY9oBl86ObM48TbvfQOec4ju8SAW603GOI0bU614CZpthHf0lTchWi6DAmyTNgsre8ICarkqJ_UrSRc3V2gExDoj1FkUjoN0qpd7oHYk196J7OwXSrfMYnxmQfqXCCVK139NASKGFTGeMfy8JLUYEvnRH1vnUvLKhBsJ7vbMgLmccLLHl6rq5K2zpXq9DZlOjIe4wJHG5wA33nW36rnv1e6Sr4sjBGJbGZqjVYA_uIz3SPk_nVFwjN3waA0K1Hcv7uNXHJxuDy0A8fqS3zc99SBMYw2dGYeF4boIMXwfekabL9WpgtZ2km72xKItU6LnPeufgNVQxaIK9ObhyM0Amd8zsjWtsaJ3UhVrd4mdv6PEaqkJwVMx3pC7CkgQdZW4msKjF3hIQxpkK3CxmqD9sSB4scgA1zRoMw9RP45NnK_dgYB1x.m3u8"></video>
```

?

By the way, how do you get the m3u8 from a live streaming from Twitch (I only access it from devtools/network in my browsers, how do you get it "automatically" ?)